# numpy: log with -inf not nans

Tags: python, numpy, nan, logarithm

Is there an efficient way to write a log-like function for a numpy array that gives `-inf` for negative numbers?

The behaviour I would like is:

```
>>> log_inf(exp(1))
1.0

>>> log_inf(0)
-inf

>>> log_inf(-1)
-inf
```

with `-inf` returned for any negative numbers.

*EDIT*: At the moment I am using `clip` to substitute negative numbers for `0`, it works but is it efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numpy *arrays* you can calculate the log and then apply a simple mask.

```
>>> a=np.exp(np.arange(-3,3,dtype=np.float))
>>> b=np.log(a)
>>> b
array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.])

>>> b[b<=0]=-np.inf
>>> b
array([-inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,   1.,   2.])
```

To save a bit of time and to have the option of calling in place or creating a new array:

```
def inf_log(arr,copy=False):
    mask= (arr<=1)
    notmask= ~mask
    if copy==True:
        out=arr.copy()
        out[notmask]=np.log(out[notmask])
        out[mask]=-np.inf
        return out
    else:
        arr[notmask]=np.log(arr[notmask])
        arr[mask]=-np.inf
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`numpy.log`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) with a conditional test for negative numbers:

```
import numpy as np
def log_inf(x):
    return np.log(x) if x>0 else -float('Inf')


log_inf(-1)
-inf
log_inf(0)
-inf
log_inf(np.exp(1))
1.0
```

With type checking:

```
def log_inf(x):
    if not isinstance(x, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
        return np.log(x) if x>0 else -float('Inf')
    else:
        pass #could insert array handling here
```

Comment: There are two serious problems with this answer.  1. The function _prints_ instead of _returning_.  That's not good!  2.  The function will not work if passed an array with more than one element because the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Given for instance a base `10` log where `log(x)` is the inverse of `10**x=100`, it is mathematically impossible to achieve `10**(-inf)==-1`.

But it is possible to achieve `10**(-inf)==0`. In `numpy` you already get:

```
np.log(0)==-np.inf
#True
```

and:

```
10**(-np.inf)==0
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is:

```
np.nan_to_num(np.log(data), neginf=0)
```

Or for many purposes, using a Numpy masked array may work well:

```
np.ma.log(data)
```